# Use google protocolBuffers have some error in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios6, protocol-buffers

When build it in my works have some error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:`
>
> > "computeDataSize(int, NSData*)", referenced from:`
> >
> > -[OuterMessage serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
> >
> > - [Secret serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o
> >
> > > -[SecretAck serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `"computeEnumSize(int, int)", referenced from:`
>
> `-[OuterMessage serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> > -[Options serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
> >
> > > > -[Options_Encoding serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `-[Configuration serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `-[KeyEvent serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `-[FlingResult serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `"computeInt32Size(int, int)", referenced from:`
>
> `-[MouseEvent serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `-[MouseWheel serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `-[Connect serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `"computeStringSize(int, NSString*)", referenced from:`
>
> `-[PairingRequest serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `-[PairingRequestAck serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `-[Connect serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `-[Fling serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `-[Data serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `"computeUInt32Size(int, int)", referenced from:`
>
> `-[OuterMessage serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `-[Options_Encoding serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `-[RemoteMessage serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `"computeMessageSize(int, objc_object*)", referenced from:`
>
> `-[Options serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `-[Configuration serializedSize] in Polo.pb.o`
>
> `-[RemoteMessage serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `-[RequestMessage serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `-[ResponseMessage serializedSize] in Remote.pb.o`
>
> `"google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32Fallback(unsigned int)", referenced from:`

`google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32(unsigned int) in 
CommandSender.o`

> `"google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint32FallbackToArray(unsigned int, unsigned char*)", referenced from:`
>
> `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint32ToArray(unsigned int, unsigned char*) in CommandSender.o`
>
> `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`
>
> `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
>
> I make `Remote.pb.h` and "Remote.pb.m" with Object-C build it.
>   about Xcode 4.6.1

Comment: I posted a comment on your [earlier question ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050486/build-goole-tv-anyrremote-keycodes-c-source-error) Was that of any help?

Comment: Try running the code on an actuall device - iphone/ipad. I had faced similar problems earlier on simulator but it worked on actual device

Comment: I'll post it as an answer pls upvote n accept

Answer (score 1):

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Try running the code on an actuall device - iphone/ipad. I had faced similar problems earlier on simulator but it worked on actual device

Comment: This is not the similar problem. In my device have some problems. @Tushar Koul